# Looping through all documents in a site through powershell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I'm new to powershell and trying to loop through all document libraries of a site using below code:

```
$webs = (Get-SPSite "XXX" | Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

$Lists = $webs.Lists

$ListItemCollection = @()

Foreach($List in $Lists) {

    if($List.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
    
    
        $list.Items | Where-Object { $_["Choice Column"] -eq $null } | foreach {
        

            $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
            $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "URL" -value $_.URL
            $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Name" -value $_["Name"]
            $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
        }
    }
    }

$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "D:\Test\Logs.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

The output in txt file contains those files also which doesn't have the custom column(Choice Column).
Do I need to check if the Document library contains the custom field and if so how can i check it.

Please note we are using Sharepoint 2016 on-premise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to retreive all document one a site or more is using search

Use ContentTypeId and path in your query

```
param([string]$siteCollectionUrl="http://mySiteUrl" ,
```

$keyword="ContentTypeId:0x010100020D149374FFC4DF792F30EFC030C9D01* ",
$rowLimit=500,
$SelectProperties="Title,SPWebUrl,Path"
)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$site = Get-SPSite $siteCollectionUrl
$keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($site);

#set request
$keywordQuery.QueryText = $keyword

#set managed properties to retreive
foreach($mnp in $SelectProperties.Split(","))
{
$keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add($mnp.Trim());
}
$keywordQuery.RowLimit = $rowLimit

$searchExec = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor
$searchResults = $searchExec.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)

#display results
$table = $searchResults.Table
$table | Select Title, SPWebUrl, Path

$site.Dispose()

[Powershell script helper](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/powershell/sharepointpowershellquerysearchservice.html)